# taking input in while loop overrides the same line in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

when i try to read command line arguments using while loop in bash it overwrites the prompt how i can prevent this problem and i cant remove the -r flag in read command if i do that i won't be able to use arrow keys

[image]

sample of code is here

```
while :
do

        #easy life things


        name=$(whoami)
        prompt=$'\033[1;33m;-)\033[0m\033[1;31m'${name}$'\033[0m\033[1;34m@'$(hostname)$'\033[0m\033[1;32m>>\033[0m\033[1;31m️ \033[0m' ;
        echo -n -e "${blue}"
        read -r -e -p "${prompt} " cmd
        history -s ${cmd}
        echo -n -e "${nc}"
//the code that got erased doesn't have any problem the problem is with the read command
done
```

i was expecting that it should not overwrite the same line without removing those two flags in read command

Comment: What is `${nc}`?

Comment: I think the problem is with the `-n` option in `echo -n -e "${nc}"`. That leaves you on the same line, and the next prompt is written there.

Comment: nope problem still remains same if i remove that no newline flag (-n)

Comment: ${nc} it's a variable that tells that after printing this it will not color any kinda output

Comment: Where is the `ls` output coming from? I don't see anything that executes `$cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

The script snippet you gave does not represent the environment or code which generated the conditions shown in the image provided.

What you show in the image is a condition some encounter when the **PS1 prompt string** is incorrectly defined, containing some malformed color-coding sequences.

You are facing the same conditions encountered in the situation presented in this other [**Question**](https://superuser.com/questions/1756567/changing-bash-ps1-colors-ruins-bash-command-line), where I gave a detailed explanation for the conditions there.